# Unable to do automatic updation in the slave server

Tags: windows-server-2003, bind, master-slave

I've installed BIND 9.5.2-P1 running in Windows Server 2003. There is 1 master server and 1 slave server. i already have master that work well for our zones. The problem is my slave server didn't update from master automatically. But all the zone files and .conf file was transferrenred to the slave when i set set the slave server in the beginning. i'm new to the study of  DNS and just practising for a month only.Please help me out in this. Is there any software that i should load in my slave server for it to update automatically? Or is there any command i have to add to do the updation. i want to update automatically.

**The following is my master configurations:**

```
  options {

  directory "c:\named\zones"; 

  recursion no;

  notify yes;

  };

  zone "mydns.com" IN {

  type master;

  file "db.mydns.com.txt";

  };
```

**The following is my slave configurations:**

```
  options {

  directory "c:\named\zones";

  recursion no;

  };


 zone "mydns.com" IN {

  type slave;

 file "bak.db.mydns.com.txt";

 masters { 192.168.0.17 ; };

 };
```

Comment: I have incremented the serial number and reloaded the rndc also. yet not working!!!I have not configured any log files and no idea about log files. do we have to configure log files to make the automatic updation of the slave server working. Tell me about log files also. Thank You

Comment: Looks like bind puts the logs either in the event viewer or `%windir%\systems32\dns\` somewhere there should be log files in there that you can look at for erros. Please post those here

Answer (score 1):

Please post your NS records.

If the slave is not listed in the NS records, the notify will never be sent.  also, make certain the slave can transfer from the master using

```
dig @master-ip-address +vc example.com axfr
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you increment the serial field when you updated your zone? Did you issue an `rndc reload`command after you updated the field.

What is in the bind log files?

Answer (score 0):

Also, do you have multiple IP addresses? In that case you may need to add `notify-source`.